# Kubernetes and istio sidecar automatic injection

Tags: kubernetes, istio, microk8s

I'm trying to set up the automatic sidecar injection for istio on Kubernetes on-premises (istio 1.1.5 k8s 1.13.5).

Once I labeled my namespace as `istio-injection=enabled` I got on my pod the following error for istio-sidecar container

```
Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with status code: 503
```

If I try to inject manually the sidecar container it works.
How can I solve?

Comment: even i am facing this issue..you can check this post https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/9504#issuecomment-439432130

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the label from the node.
Instead add istio injector annotation to the deployment manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. Until then there is not service pointing the container port the istio-proxy container will be in unhealthly status.